# AWS - Cloudwatch events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have an ec2 and a folder, I want that whenever a file is added in that folder, an already created lambda is executed. Would it be advisable to use cloudwatch events with a trigger with cron?
How can I make the trigger run by itself?

I have read about cloudwatch events and task scheduler with a script

Comment: Where is this 'folder'? Is it on the Amazon EC2 instance? If so, you would need to have some code running on the EC2 instance that somehow detects the creation of the file and invokes the Lambda function. AWS services are not able to 'see' what is stored on an EC2 instance because it is managed and protected by the Operating System running on the instance. An alternative is to store the file in an Amazon S3 bucket -- the bucket can then be configured to trigger an AWS Lambda function when the file is created.